# Getting \needspace to work in multicols

Tags: line-breaking, multicol

I have code that generates multiple lists of data in the form of XeLaTeX source.  Because the lines of data are very short, I'm presenting it in a `multicols` environment.  Each list has a few headings in it. Occasionally the list of data is very short – just a single heading and one line of data – and in this case, I'm struggling to prevent the heading and following line from being split across columns.  Here's a MWE showing the problem and my attempt to fix it using `\needspace`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{needspace}
\newcommand{\tblheading}[1]{\needspace{2\baselineskip}\textbf{#1}\newline}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\tblheading{Heading}
Entry
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I've tried using `\Needspace*` instead of `\needspace`, I've also tried adding `\raggedcolumns`, increasing the requested space from `2\baselineskip`, and using `\par`, `\\` or `\\*` instead of `\newline`,  but whatever I try, I cannot prevent these two lines from being split between two columns.  Can anyone help?

(I know that in principle I could use a `minipage` or perhaps `samepage` environment, but I don't think that's possible here because I really need to keep the special handling within the `\tblheading` macro due to the way the data is generated.)

Comment: why don't you define a real heading command?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer – what do you mean?  I can't use `\section`, `\subsection`, etc., as they're already in use in the document.

Comment: well \subsection doesn't fall from the sky, it is defined in your class, and you can define more such commands if you want. Or you could use `scrartcl` as class and  `\minisec{Heading}`.

Comment: Changing to `scrartcl` breaks far too much, so that's not an option, though it does fix this particular problem.  I've no idea what you mean when you say I can define more commands line `\subsection`.  Isn't that what I've done?  Presumably I've missed something relevant from my definition of `\tblheading`, but I don't know what – that's why I've posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

The \minisec command of KOMA does more or less this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\minisec[1]{%
    \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
    \par
    \@afterindentfalse
    \if@nobreak
      \everypar{}%
    \else
      \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{1.5ex}% space before, adjust if needed
    \fi
  {\parindent \z@
   \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}
    \normalfont\bfseries
    \nobreak\interlinepenalty \@M #1\par\nobreak%
  }\nobreak
  \@afterheading
}                              
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\minisec{Heading}
Entry
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to break inside the `hangpara` environment – or rather, the column breaking continues to work correctly, but `hangpara` stops working.  I'm not going to be able to fix this myself because I haven't the faintest idea what your answer is doing or how it does it.

Comment: it does nothing much different to a \subsection command. Try if it works if you comment the \everypar{}.

Answer (score 0):

Multicol actually formats the entire page as a single column, then splits it into two or more equal lengths.  It turns out that `\@afterheading` will not prevent this split from taking place, so `\subsection*` etc won't work either.  My old version of `\needspace` will work, fortunately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tblheading}[1]{\par\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr 2\baselineskip-\dp\strutbox}\vspace{-2\baselineskip}\newline
  \indent\textbf{#1}\newline}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\noindent\rule{\columnwidth}{49\baselineskip}% 48 will go in first column

\tblheading{Heading}
Entry

\lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```